# How can I import `str::to_string` in Rust? (And is it possible to do this with trait methods in general?)

Tags: rust, traits

I want to turn a `&str` into a `String` which can be done simply with the method

`let res = "my_string".to_string()`

I prefer thinking of methods as acting directly on a structure so I'd like to write

`let res = to_string("my_string")`.

The closest I've come to this so far is: `str::to_string("my_string")` but providing the namespace seems a bit verbose an unnecessary so I want to import the function into my namespace but I haven't found a way to do it that doesn't make the the compiler complain.

I thought that `use std::str::to_string;` would do the trick but the compiler says "no `to_string` in `str`".

I checked the source for `str::to_string` and realized that it appears to be the implementation of a trait but this is illegal `use std::string::ToString::to_string;` which makes sense because you wouldn't be able to differentiate between which struct implemented the trait.

So this brings me to my closely related questions:

1. How do I import the `to_string` method for `str` directly?
2. Why does `std::str::to_string` not work given that `str::to_string` is in the namespace?
3. In general, is there a way to invoke trait methods on an object using `trait_method(obj)` syntax instead of `obj.trait_method()` syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You cannot.
2. Because:

   a) It is not; `ToString` is implemented on the *type* `str`, and `std::str` is a separate module defined in `std` (so `str::to_string` if anything, without `std`).

   b) You cannot import trait methods.
3. Not without specifying the trait (`Trait::trait_method(obj)`).